# Laravel | Redirect Does Not Change URL

Tags: laravel, redirect, iframe, laravel-controller

I am using an API from a payments-provider.

At some point, I show the user a page where he can authenticate himself (enter a code that the payment-provider will send him).
Note that on this page, I render a `div` element that the payment-provider has given me through an API request I made previously (I used Guzzle for this).

After the user enters the code and clicks submit, the payment-provider redirects him to one of my pages - let's say `/redirect`.
So, in my `web.php` I have a route:

```
Route::post('/redirect', 'OrdersController@redirect');
```

In my OrdersController I do this:

```
// do various stuff like updating the order status

return redirect("orders/$order->id");
```

There is another route in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/orders/{order}', 'OrdersController@show');
```

And here is the `show` method:

```
return view('orders/show', [
    'order' => $order,
    'page_title' => 'Order Receipt',
]);
```

Two things go wrong:

1. The user gets shown the `orders/show` view but it seems like it is in an iframe:
   [image]
2. The URL of the page does not change. It does not show `myapp.test/orders/435` for example. Instead, it still shows the URL of the previous page (the one where the user authenticated himself) - something like `myapp.test/authenticate` let's say.

Any ideas why this is happening?

---

Update with screenshot:
[image]

Comment: `On this page, I render a div element that the payment-provider has given me through an API request I made previously` -> does it contain an iframe?

Comment: "_but it seems like it is in an iframe_" You could easily check if there's an iframe by looking at the HTML source of the page

Comment: `return view('orders/show')` shouldn't be `return view('orders.show')`? A dot instead of slash?

Comment: @VadimSirbu I have updated the description with a screenshot. My page gets displayed inside an iframe.

Comment: @brombeer you are right of course - I was too drowsy to think of that - description updated

Comment: @KazikM it's the same thing.

Comment: I have overcome this by using JS to redirect from within the view. Of course, this is a hack. The issue remains. Just FYI this issue is occurring while using Mastercard's Payment Gateway service.